# Siddur with lots of white space for notes

Tags: tefilla, product-recommendation, jewish-books, prayer-book

I'm interested in making extensive notes on a siddur - for my own use, inspired partially by [this recommendation](http://rechovot.blogspot.com/2011/10/write-in-your-siddur.html). Are there any editions of the Siddur out there that include a great deal of white space, either explicitly for personal notes or just convenient for that?

I realize that the white space in many regular siddurim may be sufficient, but I'd like to have enough space without crowding into a small space or interfering with the actual text.

Comment: Are you looking for a bound, print edition, or would printing your own (with whatever margins you like) and putting it in a binder work?

Comment: I don't know of a sidur especially designed for it, but I personally have no problem fitting writing into my Artscroll (small edition) weekday sidur (mostly just changing the nusach of one word, but also sometimes some lengthy sentences, such as copying the "hareini mekabel alai," etc. from Chayei Adam (klal 1)

Comment: @MonicaCellio I suppose I'd be open to that option.

Comment: ... though something bound already would certainly be easier.

Comment: what nusach? +1

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman, I use Nusach Ashkenaz, but I'll leave the question ambiguous.

Comment: How much writing do you plan on doing?  I've always felt that Artscroll has an excessive amount of white space in it, not to mention good quality paper for writing (and erasing and rewriting).  I take it that you don't find that to be adequate?

Comment: http://nleresources.com/kiruv-and-chinuch/online-books/nle-teaching-books/siddur/

Comment: [Siddur Tefillath Yosef](http://www.mysefer.com/product.asp?cookiecheck=yes&P_ID=3879&strPageHistory=related) doesn't leave much room (or have good paper) for writing notes, but it has tons of commentary, in addition to all the relevant rulings of the Mishnah Berurah.

Comment: Post it notes. Use a mechanical pencil, which will allow you to write very small.

Comment: I've mentioned this question in a comment to [this one](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/51348/5323). Do you have any thoughts on that question?

Comment: @Shokhet, I agree with [sabahillel](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/51348/is-highlighting-text-and-writing-in-the-siddur-ok#comment136152_51348)

Comment: @IsaacMoses [Fine](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/51357/5323).

Answer (score 4):

http://opensiddur.org/category/contributions/siddurim/ contains several whole siddurim whose copyright has expired.  You can print out the PDFs and bind them however you'd like.

### From the founder, in a comment below:

While we are engaged in the transcription of liturgical works that are historical and often pre-date 1923 (and the origin of Copyright law in general), most of the work that is being shared at the Open Siddur are work that are under Copyright but whose Copyright owners are sharing with special free-culture Copyright licenses permitting their adoption, adaptation, and redistribution so long as proper credit and attribution are provided.

--Aharon Varady, founding director/hierophant, the Open Siddur Project

Comment: Also, you can see what is available on [hebrewbooks.org](http://www.hebrewbooks.org) - you can order prints from http://www.publishyoursefer.com/

Comment: Just a slight correction to what Charles wrote. While we are engaged in the transcription of liturgical works that are historical and often pre-date 1923 (and the origin of Copyright law in general), most of the work that is being shared at the Open Siddur are work that are under Copyright but whose Copyright owners are sharing with special free-culture Copyright licenses permitting their adoption, adaptation, and redistribution so long as proper credit and attribution are provided. --Aharon Varady, founding director/hierophant, the Open Siddur Project

Comment: @aharonium, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks for your correction. I hope you stick around and enjoy the site, including our 77 other _[tag:sidur]_ questions.

Answer (score 3):

The Koren Ani Tefilla Siddur [(Weekday](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/9653016687) and [Shabbos](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/9653016857)) has a lot of white space at the bottom of pages explicitly for the purpose of writing notes for oneself.

Comment: This looks awesome. I just might buy one. Do you have one? If so, could you add a photo of a representative page (or part of a page) to this post? I believe such reproduction for review purposes would be allowed under Fair Use.

Comment: @IsaacMoses Unfortunately I do not.

Comment: @IsaacMoses [Here](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e0/Baruch_Sheamar_prayer_Koren_Siddur.jpg) is a sample page, featuring _Baruch Sheamar_.

Answer (score 2):

Some children's siddurim leave a lot of space for writing,

This Artscroll leaves more room than most other siddurim

http://www.artscroll.com/Books/scha.html

I am sure if you go into a seforim store and look in their siddurim aisle, there would be more editions of a children's siddur with even more room.

Answer (score 2):

After reading this question last night, I noticed as I davened from the [Koren-Sacks siddur](http://www.korenpub.com/EN/series/siddur/Series/5) today that in many places it has extensive white space.  Notably, in the amida there is a lot of white space.  So if a lot of your notes are going there, you might find it appealing (in addition to its other positive features).