# Is highlighting text and writing in the siddur OK?

Tags: prayer-book, writing-printing

I want to highlight parts of the prayers where the congregation responds and where the chazzan speaks so I can better follow the service, as well as write in some notes about the prayer order, etc. Can I write in the siddur or will my rabbi have a meltdown? =)

Comment: I don't see an issue with it, and I've seen it done, but I don't have any authoritative sources for you at the moment.

Comment: Isaac Moses assumes you can in [this question](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/20512/5323). His question is based off of [this blog post](http://rechovot.blogspot.com/2011/10/write-in-your-siddur.html), where the [Rebbetzin's Husband](http://rechovot.blogspot.com/) recommends it.

Comment: @Shokhet You should make this an answer.

Comment: Is it your own siddur?

Comment: Yes. I don't write on other people's property. It's called vandalism =)

Comment: Artscroll did it by putting seasonal prayers in grey boxes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While I've never done this myself, I don't see any issue with it, provided that you highlight and underline respectfully.

In fact, the practice comes [highly recommended by the Rebbetzin's Husband](http://rechovot.blogspot.com/2011/10/write-in-your-siddur.html), and has also been discussed [elsewhere on this site](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/20512/5323).

From that blog post:

> It's a way to corral ourselves during our distracted moments, and draw
>   ourselves back.
>   It's a way to personalize our davening, by
>   highlighting elements that matter to us.
>   It's a way to remember the
>   items that catch our eye or ear and inspire us once, for the next time
>   we daven.

So it seems that it's not just something that you *may* do, but rather a recommended practice. I wish you much success in [focusing on your prayers](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/190/5323)!

Comment: I discovered this answer while wondering whether it was ok to copy the sources for text (eg "Psalm xx:yy") from a nicely informative siddur into one without footnotes. I get the impression this would be acceptable too?

Comment: @chrysanthemum I don't see why that would be an issue. The only issue that comes to mind is one of copyright, which shouldn't be a problem if you're not selling/distributing your siddur.

Comment: @shokhet Thank for. I own both and its purely for my own personal use :)

Answer (score 2):

My answer is based on logical deduction.

Many siddurim already include typed English instructions and translations, etc. interspersed between the Hebrew prayers. I don't see the difference whether the publisher has typed instructions or whether you highlight or write your own instructions to help you out.

Answer (score 1):

Provided you're not erasing G-d's name, there should be no problem.

Comment: (Also provided it is your own siddur.)